# Java socket multiple writes and reads

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I want to write a client that can communicate to `Vowpal Wabbit` over TCP. Essentially, I need to send messages like `a b | c d e` to VW host over port 26542. VW responds with a message like `0.400000 0.200000 0.200000 0.200000` (not sure how the message terminates).

So, I need to do this multiple times - send message, receive message, send message, receive message, and so on.

I have the following code in Java.

```
public class MyClient {
    protected String host;
    protected int port;
    protected Socket socket;
    protected PrintWriter outputWriter;
    protected BufferedReader inputReader;

    public MyClient(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        outputWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }

    public void send(final String message) throws IOException {
        outputWriter.print(message+"\n"); // important to add a newline
        outputWriter.flush();

        String responseStr = inputReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(responseStr);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(responseStr)) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I use this class as follows:

```
MyClient client = new MyClient("host_ip", 26542); // the port used by VW
client.send("1:0.5:0.3 | feature11 feature21 feature31");
client.send("1:0.5:0.3 | feature12 feature22 feature32");
client.send("1:0.5:0.3 | feature13 feature23 feature33");
```

With the above code, only the response of the first "send" is printed. The other two return `null` responses.

I also tried with "send" only code:

```
    public void send(final String message) throws IOException {
        outputWriter.print(message+"\n"); // important to add a newline
        outputWriter.flush();
    }
```

It turns out that only the first message is sent (I have a way of verifying/logging on server side what it receives from my client).

Why is it that only the first send succeeds but all other sends fail (although no exception is raised)? How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the response to the first message? Are you sure that your input format is correct and that you're not getting an error response to your first message? Shouldn't it be `1 0.5 0.3 | feature11 feature21 feature31` instead (spaces instead of colons) ? Looking at https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Daemon-example , that seems to be the case.

Comment: The input is correct. There are other formats too in which we can send the message to VW. I am using a different format (for contextual bandits). I also tested the message with `echo '1:0.5:0.3 | feature11 feature21 feature31' | nc vw_host 26542` and got valid return message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `readLine()` returns null, the peer has closed the connection.

Comment: So, how do I get around this issue? Should I do a `new Socket()` for each message? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: You fix the problem that is causing the server to close the connection, by examining its response, and you check your assumption that the server will read multiple responses via the same connection. In any case if it closes the connection you must do likewise and connect a new socket.

Comment: I don't know if VW is closing the connection after each exchange but I modified my code to create a new connection each time I want to send a message. With that, I am able to send and receive messages correctly. So, perhaps VW is indeed closing the connection after each exchange.

Comment: Well it is certainly closing the connection in this particular case. The `null` says so.